# How to connect outside command to rabbitmq docker container?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm doing self study using docker. I'm trying to experiment where my rabbitmq is inside the docker and my eclipse-mosquitto is outside the docker. I know there is an image for eclipse-mosquitto, but I just want to know if I can connect it outside the docker.
In my docker-compose.yml, this is my code

```
version: "3.2"
networks:
  test_network:

services:
    rabbitmq:
        container_name: rabbitmq-test
        build:
          context: ./docker/rabbitmq
        ports:
          - 5672:5672
          - 15672:15672
        volumes:
          - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
          - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
          - ./docker/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
        networks:
          - test_network
```

and then I install mosquitto using homebrew in my machine. I try this command

```
mosquitto_pub -h 172.20.0.5 -t test.hello -m "hello world" -u guest -P guest -p 1883 -d
```

I always get error `Error: Operation timed out`. I try to use the container name of rabbitmq as a host, but it doesn't work. I just want to know if this is possible?

I try this command

```
mosquitto_pub -h 0.0.0.0 -t rh.mumbai -m "miyatx" -u guest -P guest -p 1883 -d
```

I get an error

```
Client null sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.
```

Comment: have you tried using localhost?

Comment: @ShadowGunn I try that too. I get the same error above. `The connection was lost`

Comment: go to the host machine and do sudo docker network ls

Comment: I have this result `rabbitmq_default   bridge    local` .

Comment: `localhost` and port 5672 should be correct, from outside Docker, on the same host, either on a native-Linux host or using Docker Desktop.  It looks like the `ports:` settings are correct for this.  If you look at `docker-compose logs rabbitmq`, is the broker starting up successfully?